# Reference for general Arzela Ascoli theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, compactness, book-recommendation

Where can I find a reference for the general Arzela Ascoli theorem for the space $C(X,Y)$. $X$ anything, but a $Y$ Banach space?

Comment: see the appendix of Foundations of Modern Probability 3e Kallenberg

Comment: The case of $X, Y$ being compact metric spaces is covered in page 108 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf

Comment: There's a very general statement in Bourbaki's [*General Topology*](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540645634), chap. X, § 2, no. 5, with $X$ topological space and $Y$ uniform space, but that's for more general than what you're asking for...

Comment: Topological Vector Spaces, Second Edition, Lawrence Narici, page 133, Section 5.10.

Answer (score 2):

For compact metric $X$ and complete metric $Y$ you can find it as Theorem 1.5.11 in

> Abraham, Ralph, Jerrold E. Marsden, and Tudor Ratiu. Manifolds, tensor analysis, and applications. Vol. 75. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Also have a look at Theorem 3.4.20 in

> Engelking, Ryszard. "General topology." Sigma series in pure mathematics 6 (1989).

This variant is valid for arbitrary $k$-spaces $X$ and regular spaces $Y$. However, the topology on the set $C(X,Y)$ of continuous functions $X \to Y$ is the compact-open topology. For compact $X$ and metric $Y$ this topology agrees with usual metric topology induced by the $\sup$-metric.

Comment: They assume $X$ is compact.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, I overlooked this.